# Microsoft Custom Translator Portal Giving WorkspaceID error

Tags: microsoft-translator

Hope you are doing good,

We are seeing following error while accessing the Custom Translator after recent release in my account where earlier some models where already published. I am not finding any option in custom translator where we can provide WorkspaceID for which we are receiving error.

Can you please help me here to resolve this error?

Please let me know if you need more information in this regard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you logout of Custom Translator, clear your browser cache and login again, you should not see this message.  If you have any bookmarks directly into Custom Translator, they may no longer be valid.